# Jquery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

hay everyone, i have jquery code like this

```
<script>
 $('document').ready(function() {
    var masterTahun = document.querySelectorAll("#masterTahunAjaran, #masterSemester")
        for (var x = 0; x < masterTahun.length; x++) {
                if ( localStorage['myKey'] == masterTahun.options[x].value) {
                     masterTahun.selectedIndex = x;
                           }
}
 });
$("#masterTahunAjaran, #masterSemester").on('change', function() {
      localStorage['myKey'] =  this.value;  // only strings
}); 


</script>
```

i get multiple IDs (2 element ID) with method `querySelectorAll`,

but when i running in broswer , error like this

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

whats wrong in my code ? how to get 2 IDs without error ? plis help 
thanks

Comment: simple try with `masterTahun[x].value`

Comment: please check for this 
if(masterTahun.options[x].value)
{
// then put your code here
if ( localStorage['myKey'] == masterTahun.options[x].value) {
                     masterTahun.selectedIndex = x;
                           }
}

Comment: can you share the html content as well.